# Call presentModalView controller in UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to call the `presentModalViewController` on `UIView`.

I want to create one model class subclass of `UIView` and create 3 buttons with action and then add it to the `UIView`. I wrote a small code about sending a message. In that I call `presentModalViewController` and I add that view to `firstViewController`.

Is it possible?

I wrote the code in `AppDelegate->application:didReceiveLocalNotification`
After receiving a notification this view will be added to `MainViewController`

```
NotifViewModel *remainderAlert = [[NotifViewModel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 60, 250, 300)];



[remainderAlert showRemainderAlert1];

[self.viewController.view addSubview:remainderAlert];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't call `presentModalViewController` on `UIView`.

You only can 'presentModalViewController' from `UIViewController` or it's subclass (`UINavigationController`, `UITableViewController`, etc).